# TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len() on Python 3.x

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm new to coding and I've been trying to scrape a page to practice. I have everything almost ready but I don't know why it gives an error.

```
from variables import MY_URL , OUT_FILE
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
from urllib.request import urlopen as ureq
import ssl

ssl._create_default_https_context = ssl._create_unverified_context

import csv

def agarrar_pagina():

    for i in range(1,22):
        uclient = ureq(MY_URL+'categorias/todas/?page={}'.format(i))
        page_html = uclient.read()
        page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")
        contenedores = page_soup.findAll('div', {'class':'cambur'})
        contenedor=[]
        for link in contenedor:
            link = contenedor.findAll('a',['href'])
            ulink = ureq(MY_URL + link)
            page_link = ulink.read()
            ulink = close()
            uclient.close()

            return page_link
```

This is the error

```
`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "prueba.py", line 93, in <module>
    main()
  File "prueba.py", line 89, in main
    cajitas = seleccionar_caja(pagina)
  File "prueba.py", line 30, in seleccionar_caja
    page_soup = soup(html, "html.parser")
  File "C:\Users\PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\bs4\__init__.py", line 
267, in __init__
    elif len(markup) <= 256 and (
TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()`
```

Comment: can you show us what you have tried so far?

Comment: Yeah sorry, i didn't upload the code. Ups

Comment: can you give us an URL to test with which will reproduce the problem?

Comment: I was using this URL: https://www.cualescambures.com/categorias/todas/?page=1

Answer (score 0):

contenedor=[] is empty list. I think you intend to use 
contenedores

```
for link in contenedores :
            link = contenedores.findAll('a',['href'])
            ulink = ureq(MY_URL + link)
            page_link = ulink.read()
            ulink = close()
            uclient.close
```

Comment: Nope. I already tried that and it gives me the same error. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: Anyways this for loop would not work with empty lists. The error seems to on the soup line item. you can try this, page_soup = soup(page_html.content , "html.parser") or page_soup = soup(page_html.text, "html.parser")

Answer (score 0):

The function `agarrar_pagina` is not mentioned in the stacktrace. I think that is because function `agarrar_pagina` returns `None` all the time.

This happens with your code when looping on empty list or on the corrected function if anything is found with the `findall`.